# Show a dialog on provider notifcation in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I want to show a dialog box when the provider notifies of state change. However, I get the error shown below. What is the best way to achieve this kind of behaviour on notification from the provider?

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<GameModel>(
      builder: (context, gameModel, child) {
        if (gameModel.gameOver) {
         _onGameOverDialog(gameModel);
        }
       
        return WillPopScope(
....
```

I get this error when I do this

> This Overlay widget cannot be marked as needing to build because the
> framework is already in the process of building widgets.

Comment: In riverpod, you would set that up with a ref.listen, which would automatically trigger between build() cycles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could not show dialog when the app is still in the process of building widgets, try adding this "WidgetsBinding" instead to wait until the widget is fully built and show the dialog.

```
    if(gameModel.gameOver) {
        WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
          _onGameOverDialog(context, gameModel);
        });
      }
```