# How to call `showDialog` from model update?

Tags: flutter

I'm using the state-management style described [here](https://docs.flutter.dev/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple), namely via the `provider` package. But I haven't found a clean way to call `showDialog` as a result of a model change. For example

```dart
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  void build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<MyModel>(
      builder: (context, model, _) {
        // omitted
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Now, `MyModel` is updated from network events, and I want to show a dialog when one of those specific events changes the model. However, I can't set a flag and check it during `build` (it's not possible to call `showDialog` during build).

What is the proper way to accomplish this?

Comment: hey, this probably answers the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76162051/show-a-dialog-on-provider-notifcation-in-flutter/76162141#76162141

Comment: If you had used riverpod, you could have subscribed to a model's state with ref.listen, and used that as a callback moment to pop up a showDialog.  the provider package doesn't really have that capability.  At least not as easily.

Comment: @RandalSchwartz I didn't know what riverpod was. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the code bellow

```
                            InkWell(
                              onTap: () {
                                showDialog(
                                  context: context,
                                  builder: (BuildContext context) =>
                                      _buildPopupDialog(context),
                                );
                              },
                              child: Text("Button name")
                            ),
```